# scan for large arrays

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I want to use the scan function in Thrust library for large arrays but I get core dumped for array larger than 32768. I was wondering if there is another option other than thrust_scan.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
  #include <thrust/scan.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

   int main()

   {

       int *x;
       int n = 65536;
      x = (int *) malloc(n);
      for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
          x[i]=i;
      thrust::inclusive_scan(x,x+n,x);
      for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
          printf(" %d ", x[i]);
          printf("\n");

  }
```

Comment: How could I run the code? it is full of line numbers. Stack overflow isn't a free debugging service and that is all this question is.looking for - trivial, free mistake spotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
x = (int *) malloc(n);
```

allocates `n` **bytes** of storage.  You want storage for `n` integers:

```
x = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```